# What is the minimum number of states to recognize this language?

Tags: algorithm, regular-language, finite-automata, computation-theory

Definition of a language L with alphabet {a} is as follows:

> L= { a^{nk} | k > 0,n >0}.

There were four options to this question

> k+1
>
> n+1
>
> 2^(n+1)
>
> 2^(k+1)

k > 0, and n is a positive integer constant

Comment: Did you make a mistake when you copied the question? Because none of the 4 possible answers is correct.

Comment: k > 0, and n is a positive integer constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer

`n` is a constant and `k` is any positive integer.

For example, if `n` is given as 3, then the DFA must be able to accept `3a, 6a, 9a, 12a, ..`

To build such a DFA, we need 4 states. `ans=(n+1)`

Comment: But maybe `k` is a constant and `n` is any positive integer?

Comment: according to me k>0 and n is a positive integer

Comment: The language as specified is just L = {a^m | m > 0} since any m can be represented as a product of n and k. Nowhere is mentioned that n is a constant.

Comment: @user19940105 Maybe you should explain this part in your answer - this will make it clearer and more useful. Maybe you have access to the original version of OP's question, and it specifies that `n` is a constant? Maybe you have access to OP's book, and it has this convention of `k` being a parameter? Maybe it's a trick question, and all 4 possible answers are indeed incorrect (question author was in a bad mood)? Maybe you are the author of the question, and this was your intent?

Comment: I completely concur. Please share how you arrived at (n+1). It just doesn't make any sense from the problem statement given above.

Comment: k > 0, and n is a positive integer constant sorry for the misprint

Comment: I solved this question because this question is similar to a question which came in GATE paper few years ago and i remembered the methodology of solving these questions when i practiced it earlier... That is why i assumed the values as k>0 and n is a positive integer...that's all!!!